# Need to tune spark job which is long running

Tags: apache-spark

I need to pull data from oracle to Hive. My job is completed in 24 hours.
I am using spark JDBC API to pull the data.How to tune this job?

```
Oracle table info:
No of blocks:54014592
Memory in MB:421989
DRIVER_MEMORY :25 gb
EXECUTOR_CORES :5
EXECUTOR_INSTANCES :25
EXECUTOR_MEMORY :20 gb
spark Parallel Degree:25
```

## Table has 29 partitions and max partition size is 93 GB

**Logs:It has many Garbage Collection**

18/12/03 05:11:55 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 16.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 144) in 1448053 ms on bdgtr004d02h1u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 18) (36/64)
1837.013: [Full GC (System.gc())  549M->296M(25G), 0.5553646 secs]
18/12/03 05:22:11 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_44 in memory on bdgtr015d07h2u.nam.nsroot.net:36517 (size: 498.7 MB, free: 10.3 GB)
18/12/03 05:58:59 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 38.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 166) in 4271907 ms on bdgtr007d17i2u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 5) (59/64)
18/12/03 06:16:17 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_22 in memory on bdgtr006d20i2u.nam.nsroot.net:34124 (size: 705.2 MB, free: 8.4 GB)
5437.013: [Full GC (System.gc())  1121M->297M(25G), 0.6317014 secs]
18/12/03 06:17:00 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 22.1 in stage 4.0 (TID 192) in 2686834 ms on bdgtr006d20i2u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 9) (60/64)
7237.013: [Full GC (System.gc())  1112M->297M(25G), 0.7000144 secs]
18/12/03 07:02:15 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_63 in memory on bdgtr007d17i2u.nam.nsroot.net:43841 (size: 318.9 MB, free: 9.0 GB)
18/12/03 07:02:39 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 63.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 191) in 8091801 ms on bdgtr007d17i2u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 5) (61/64)
9037.014: [Full GC (System.gc())  1097M->297M(25G), 0.6828210 secs]
18/12/03 07:17:57 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_58 in memory on bdgtr002d16i2u.nam.nsroot.net:41262 (size: 247.2 MB, free: 9.6 GB)
18/12/03 07:18:17 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 58.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 186) in 9030124 ms on bdgtr002d16i2u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 25) (62/64)
18/12/03 07:21:11 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_0 in memory on bdgtr001d01h1u.nam.nsroot.net:41190 (size: 515.8 MB, free: 10.0 GB)
18/12/03 07:21:49 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 128) in 9241836 ms on bdgtr001d01h1u.nam.nsroot.net (executor 8) (63/64)
10837.013: [Full GC (System.gc())  1095M->297M(25G), 0.7272104 secs]
18/12/03 07:51:01 INFO storage.BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_10_59 in memory on bdgtr009d08i2u.nam.nsroot.net:44716 (size: 287.4 MB, free: 9.4 GB)

Comment: use `fetchSize` while using jdbc... also jdbc api has option to specify partition column wil lowerBound and upperBound value

Comment: SPRINTER_PTK is partition column and I am using fetch size as 1000 and using the upper bound and lower bound and generating the queries automatically using union all and currently it is set to 25 as degree of parallelism.
SELECT T.*,               2 AS SPRINTER_ID,  '1' AS SPRINTER_PTK FROM  SCHEMA1.TABLE_NAME T  WHERE  (ROWID BETWEEN CHARTOROWID('AAA0/HAAoAAPcpiAAA') AND  CHARTOROWID('AAA0/HAAtAAOQZOH//'))   UNION ALL....